# Stable HTTP server w/ Arduino WiFi Shield?

Tags: c, http, wifi, arduino, httpserver

I'm building my first Arduino project. You can see the basics of what I've done, here: http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2013/04/10/a-first-look-at-my-arduino-bbq-thermometer/ - it's a network enabled BBQ thermometer, to tell me when my meat is done cooking on the grill.

I've got this set up with a basic HTTP server to produce a JSON document when an HTTP request is made. All of the HTTP handing code that I'm using comes from the samples that are built in to the Arduino IDE software.

The Ethernet Shield version of this code seems to work great. It seems to run for as long as I let the thing stay plugged in / turned on. But when I switch over to my Arduino WiFi shield, and upload the WiFi version of my code - which is also based on the samples in the WiFi libraries demos - it stops responding to requests after about 10 minutes or so.

I'm using an Arduino Undo R3, with the latest Arduino WiFi shield. I've got Arduino IDE v1.0 on my Mac. Everything compiles fine, and seems to run fine for a while.

The HTTP server code very quickly starts having problems. If I put up a simple web page with jQuery.ajax calls to hit the http server every 3 seconds, approximately 1 in 3 requests will fail, almost immediately. Once it moves beyond 10+ minutes, the HTTP server code on the Arduino just stops responding entirely.

It's as if I have a resource leak on HTTP clients, and they aren't being cleaned up... but this is a total guess.

For the gist of what I'm doing, see the code found here: https://github.com/arduino/wifishield/tree/master/libraries/WiFi/examples/WifiWebServer

I've literally just copy & pasted this code, turned it on, and then it starts erroring out. I don't even have to modify the code anymore than setting the right SSID and password, and setting a CORS: * header in the HTTP response. Once I upload it to my Arduino, it starts bombing requests frequently, and a few minutes later, it stops responding entirely.

Has anyone seen this problem before, with the WiFi shield? Does anyone have better HTTP request handling code for the Arduino WiFi shield?

I can provide more information, my actual code, or whatever else is needed, as well.

Comment: Not an answer to this question, but a thought regarding your quest for longer battery life. While checking the specs of the AVR in the Heli/Plane RC transmitter I have, I read the Atmel_AVR page at wikipedia. I noticed the following text: `"The Butterfly's ATmega169 CPU is capable of speeds up to 8 MHz, but it is factory set by software to 2 MHz to preserve the button battery life"`

Comment: I'm currently testing out this code: http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/WebServerST and it seems to be performing much more reliably. I'll have to dig in to really understand what the differences are, but I'm optimistic at this point.

Comment: Jeepers! That code certainly looks easy to digest. And in fact, since reading your post and the first link in it, I'm about ready to order a RasPi, an Arduino Mega2560 and a ethernet shield. Thanks for renewing my interest. Next weekend is looking fun!

Comment: Try upgrading Arduino IDE to the newest version (1.0.1, AFAIK)

Comment: I've updated to the latest Arduino IDE (v1.0.4) and the above code - both the original, and the Playground version that I linked to, are still crashing. They stop handling HTTP requests rather quickly. It's really getting frustrating :(